# Trying to get the Hello Android tutorial to work on Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, osx-leopard

I'm on Mac OS X Leopard and installed the ADT plugin into Eclipse
Galileo.  I followed all the steps on the Android developer SDK page to get started.  My SDK version is 2.2 API 8 revision 2 and I just used the Hello World
tutorial found here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

When I first created the Android application, I saw this error in the
Eclipse console:

[2010-11-13 18:20:43 - HelloAndroid] ERROR: Unable to open class
file /
Users/mydirectory/Documents/workspace/HelloAndroid/gen/com/example/
helloandroid/R.java: No such file or directory

I commented out this line to fill in the few lines from the tutorial:

setContentView(R.layout.main);

When I ran the app, it launched my emulator but all I saw was a
vertical screen on the left that said "ANDROID" and phone buttons on
the right.  I did not see the "Hello, Android" text from the
tutorial.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Run project clean to force R.java generation.

Project -> Clean... -> OK

This should make the SDK to build your project correctly. Same problem happens to me pretty often with new projects.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse ADT plugin auto-generates the R.java file based on the XML files in the res/ folder.  If there's an error in one of those XML files, then the R file won't be generated.  So check to see if Eclipse detects any errors in your resource XML files.